# Как отобразить ссылку на PDF файл в HTML?

Tags: html, pdf, google-drive

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-LOgMPHPJYkUiwD06n9Ja070MT3JsRTj/view" frameborder="0" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Проблема в том, что ссылка не ведет на конечный файл .PDF. Можно ли его как-то отобразить?

Comment: Это тип защита от нежелательных действий. Сам ненавижу всякие дибильные заголовки выставлять, в частности подробнее тут - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно поменять хвост у ссылки с view на preview

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-LOgMPHPJYkUiwD06n9Ja070MT3JsRTj/preview" frameborder="0" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>
```